# Automatically enabling webcam in mozilla and chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs

I am a java developer and in my project I have got a requirement that i have to record a video and i have to save it to database. When the request goes to video recording page every time it is asking to enable webcam and users are complaining about it. Is there any way to automatically enable webcam using java or by using angular js. here is my code in angular js.

```
<div id="divenablecamtxt" style="color: #ff0000; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div i18n="vid.enable" >Please face camera and click on   ENABLE CAMERA to start recording and say the above sentence during recording.</div>
</div>
<button class="CMN_Btns RedBG" type="button" id="enablecamera" value="ENABLE CAMERA" style="width: 180px;" i18n="video.ena" >ENABLE CAMERA</button>
```

[screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHtkg.png)

Comment: `Is there any way to automatically enable webcam` for security reasons ... no ... an end user has to enable (at least once) - `using java` ... what's that? I don't think I've installed java on a computer in 10 malware free years ...

Comment: Though I agree with your first point, I don't think your second point about Java is necessary :(

Comment: No, you can't. It has to be user's choice.

Comment: You can ask the user using HTML5 and Javascript https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm And that preference can be remembered. Chrome implements the Permissions API in navigator.permissions, and that applies to both camera and microphone permissions too.